# Yesod Whamlet render as HTML without being escaped

Tags: haskell, yesod

```
[whamlet|

          <h2> Here's the ES results:
           <h1>
            <ul>
                $forall EsHighlight high <- highlights re
                    <li>
                        <br>
                        #{toHtml high}

      |]
```

high is something like this:

```
"large <em>bamboo</em>, and a crotched stick. Throwing these down, he poked under a pile of rubbish, and brought out a rough block of wood, pierced through and through with a hole, which was immediately clapped on the top of the jar. Then planting the crotched stick upright about two yards distant, and making it sustain one end of the <em>bamboo</em>, he inserted the other end of the latter into the hole in the block: concluding these arrangements by placing an old calabash under the farther end of the <em>bamboo</em>."
```

The problem is that `<em>` is not rendered into html but remained string. So the webpage show `<em>` itself.
What can I do?

Comment: Use ^{...} Instead.

Comment: @mb14 thx but it's not working

Comment: to use ^{..} you need have a widget instead of a string (or text). You need transform somehow `high` to be a widget (maybe generate it using `[whamlet|..|]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a protection against XSS attacks, the default behavior of Hamlet (and the underlying blaze-html library) is to escape all HTML entities via the `toHtml` function. If you want to avoid that escaping, you can use [preEscapedToHtml](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.19/blaze-html-0.8.1.3/Text-Blaze-Html.html#v:preEscapedToHtml). Note that using this function on user-supplied data is *highly dangerous*.